# How to define unique constraint on multiple columns in multiple tables in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some tables, let's say 2 for simplicity:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    name varchar
    ...
);
CREATE TABLE B (
    name varchar
    ...
);
```

These tables have different structures but all have the same column (`name`)

I want to add a unique constraint on all of these columns in all of these tables.

How can I do this? This seems like a simple thing but my googling haven't proven successful so far. Most existing questions seem to deal with multiple columns in the same table.

Comment: So, do you want that a name inserted in table A could not be inserted in table B (or C, or D, ...)?

Comment: That's right, the values in all those columns in all those tables should all be unique.

Comment: This can also be viewed as PostgreSQL inheritance, where the `name` property belongs to the abstract entity and it's UNIQUE there.

Answer (score 2):

Since `UNIQUE` constraints cannot span multiple tables, you'll need to create an extra table to store all the names. Then each table will have a foreign key against the extra table.

For example:

```
create table all_names (
  zone int not null,
  name varchar(20) not null,
  constraint uq1 unique (zone, name),
  constraint uq2 unique (name) -- this is the critical constraint!
);

create table a (
  zone int not null default 1 check (zone = 1),
  name varchar(20) not null,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (zone, name) references all_names (zone, name)
);

insert into all_names (zone, name) values (1, 'Jenny'); -- succeeds
insert into a (name) values ('Jenny'); -- succeeds

create table b (
  zone int not null default 2 check (zone = 2),
  name varchar(20) not null,
  constraint fk2 foreign key (zone, name) references all_names (zone, name)
);

insert into all_names (zone, name) values (2, 'Ivan'); -- succeeds
insert into b (name) values ('Ivan'); -- succeeds

insert into all_names (zone, name) values (2, 'Jenny'); -- fails!
insert into b (name) values ('Jenny'); -- fails!
```

Note that each insert now requires an extra insert in the extra `all_names` table. This can, however, be automated (and happen behind the scenes) by the use of a pre/post-insert trigger (not shown).

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ipPJMsySYDGyqzUGwsV1Fe/0).

If you implement a trigger, then your inserts will look simple, as in:

```
insert into a (name) values ('Jenny'); -- succeeds
insert into b (name) values ('Ivan'); -- succeeds
insert into b (name) values ('Jenny'); -- fails!
```